# How to chain a sequence of optional operations to be performed onto a "variable"?

Tags: haskell

Is there some pattern to reduce repeated and consistent use of `if`s?

Let me explain. Some algorithms are inherently procedural and rely on modifying the state of a variable/object/array through time. Doing that in Haskell isn't that difficult, we just declare a different variable for each step. The problem is that sometimes we only want to change the state of a variable when that variable meets a condition, which often requires a lot of `if`s or `case`s.

So, for example, consider the following rather ugly piece of code:

```
import           Data.List                              (foldl')
import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq
import           Data.Sequence                          ((|>))

sequencialOps :: Int -> (Int, Seq.Seq (Either Bool Int))
sequencialOps init = foldl' manySteps (init, Seq.empty) [0..init]
  where
    manySteps (val, valseq) time = if time `mod` 2 == 0
                                     then intermediateSteps (2*val-9)
                                     else (val, valseq)
      where
        intermediateSteps someNum = (newnum3-1, numseq3 |> Right (newnum2-1))
          where
            (newnum1, numseq1) = if someNum > 10 || someNum < 12
                                    then (-someNum `div` 3, valseq |> Left True)
                                    else (someNum, valseq)
            (newnum2, numseq2) = if someNum `mod` 3 == 0
                                    then (-(someNum `mod` 970), numseq1 |> Right newnum1)
                                    else (newnum1, numseq1)
            (newnum3, numseq3) = if someNum == 0
                                    then (time, numseq2 |> Left False)
                                    else (newnum2, numseq2)

main = print $ sequencialOps 6
```

I'm running the same procedure `manySteps` many times. `manySteps` modifies the value I pass it (`val`) only sometimes (under specific conditions).

So, it's there some custom monad or clever way to write the code above so it doesn't overuse `if`s (or `case`s)?

I was thinking that maybe the solution is to use the `State` monad, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

**Edit:**

The dummy program above is just an example of a little longer code. What I'm actually trying to write is a small implementation of the Gauss-Jordan algorithm.

Here goes my implementation (using safe, hmatrix and containers):

```
import           Data.List                              (foldl')
import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq
import           Data.Sequence                          ((|>))
import           Data.Maybe                             (fromJust)
import           Data.Foldable                          (toList)
import           Safe.Exact as SP

import           Data.Semigroup                         ((<>))

import           Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Data hiding (toList, (|>))

main = do
  let matrix = (2 >< 3) [1,2,3,4,5,6] :: Matrix Double
  print matrix
  print $ gaussJordan matrix
  pure ()

data GJOperations =
    MutiplyRowBy Int Double       -- ^ Row and Value to multiply
  | ExchangeRows Int Int          -- ^ Row 1 and Row 2
  | AddMulRowToRow Double Int Int -- ^ Value to multipy to Row 1 to add to Row 2
  deriving (Show)

exchangeRows :: Int -> Int -> Matrix Double -> Maybe (Matrix Double)
exchangeRows i j mat = fromRows <$> newRows
  where asRows = toRows mat
        (i',j') = if i<j then (i,j) else (j,i)
        newRows = do
          (rws1, rest1) <- SP.splitAtExactMay i' asRows
          (rowI, rest2) <- SP.splitAtExactMay 1 rest1
          (rws2, rest3) <- SP.splitAtExactMay (j'-i'-1) rest2
          (rowJ, rws3)  <- SP.splitAtExactMay 1 rest3
          pure $ rws1 <> rowJ <> rws2 <> rowI <> rws3

multiplyRowby :: Double -> Int -> Matrix Double -> Maybe (Matrix Double)
multiplyRowby val i mat = fromRows <$> newRows
  where asRows = toRows mat
        cols = size (head asRows)
        newRows = do
          (rws1, rest1)  <- SP.splitAtExactMay i asRows
          ([rowI], rws2) <- SP.splitAtExactMay 1 rest1
          pure $ rws1 <> [konst val cols * rowI] <> rws2

addMulRowToRow :: Double -> Int -> Int -> Matrix Double -> Maybe (Matrix Double)
addMulRowToRow val i j mat = fromRows <$> newRows
  where asRows = toRows mat
        (i',j') = if i<j then (i,j) else (j,i)
        cols = size (head asRows)
        newRows = do
          (rws1, rest1)   <- SP.splitAtExactMay i' asRows
          ([rowI], rest2) <- SP.splitAtExactMay 1 rest1
          (rws2, rest3)   <- SP.splitAtExactMay (j'-i'-1) rest2
          ([rowJ], rws3)  <- SP.splitAtExactMay 1 rest3
          pure $ if i < j
                    then rws1 <> [rowI] <> rws2 <> [rowJ + konst val cols * rowI] <> rws3
                    else rws1 <> [rowI + konst val cols * rowJ] <> rws2 <> [rowJ] <> rws3

gaussJordan :: Matrix Double -> (Matrix Double, [GJOperations])
gaussJordan mat = (\(a,_,o)->(a, toList o)) $ foldl' simplifyCol (mat, 0, Seq.empty) [0..cols-1]
  where
    (rows, cols) = size mat

    simplifyCol nochange@(mat', row, gjops) col = case newrow of
                                           Just nrow -> calculateSteps nrow
                                           Nothing   -> nochange
      where
        newrow = findRow row
        findRow i
          | i == rows = Nothing
          | colcontent ! i /= 0 = Just i
          | otherwise = findRow (i+1)
        colcontent = toColumns mat' !! col

        calculateSteps nrow = (newmat2, row+1, newgjops2)
          where
            valCurrentRow = colcontent ! nrow

            -- Assuming I get always a Just, I think I always get it but it is nonetheless awful
            createUnwrap f = fromJust . f

            nextvalues = if valCurrentRow == 1
                            then (mat', gjops)
                            else (createUnwrap (multiplyRowby (1/valCurrentRow) nrow) mat', gjops |> MutiplyRowBy nrow (1/valCurrentRow))

            (newmat, newgjops) = foldl' calculateRowStep nextvalues [r | r<-[0..rows-1], r/=nrow]

            (newmat2, newgjops2) = if row == nrow
                                      then (newmat, newgjops)
                                      else (createUnwrap (exchangeRows row nrow) newmat, newgjops |> ExchangeRows row nrow)

            calculateRowStep orig@(mat'', gjops') r =
              let valOtherRow = colcontent ! r
                  change = (- valOtherRow)
                  newmat' = createUnwrap (addMulRowToRow change nrow r) mat''
               in if valOtherRow == 0.0
                     then orig
                     else (newmat', gjops' |> AddMulRowToRow change nrow r)
```

The code works, but it's kinda hard to understand, way too many levels of scoping and many `if`s and `case`s. T_T

Comment: The `State` monad in conjunction with `when` sounds like it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use monads to write cleaner-looking code which modifies state:

```
sequentialOps :: Int -> (Int, Seq.Seq (Either Bool Int))
sequentialOps init = run (traverse_ manySteps [0..init])
  where
    manySteps time = when (even time) $ do
      val <- get
      let someNum = 2*val-9
      when (someNum > 10 || someNum < 12) $ do
        put (-someNum `div` 3)
        log (Left True)
      when (someNum `mod` 3 == 0) $ do
        gets Right >>= log
        put (-(someNum `mod` 970))
      num2 <- get
      when (someNum == 0) $ do
        log (Left False)
        put time
      modify pred
      log (Right (num2-1))
    log = tell . Seq.singleton
    run = runWriter . flip execStateT init
```

However, in general, a lot of algorithms which might *seem* "inherently procedural" aren't in practice. In this case, for instance: you're repeatedly appending to a sequence. Could you perhaps use an unfold instead?

There's also several superfluous conditions in the code, `someNum > 10 || someNum < 12` is always true, for instance. Also, I don't think `log (Left False)` is ever called. Using those points, you can simplify a little:

```
sequentialOps :: Int -> (Int, Seq.Seq (Maybe Int))
sequentialOps init = run (replicateM_ (1 + init `div` 2) manySteps)
  where
    manySteps = do
      val <- get
      let someNum = 2*val-9
      put (-someNum `div` 3)
      log Nothing
      when (someNum `mod` 3 == 0) $ do
        gets Just >>= log
        put (-(someNum `mod` 970))
      modify pred
      gets Just >>= log
    log = tell . Seq.singleton
    run = runWriter . flip execStateT init
```

What is it exactly you're trying to do with this code? If I had an idea of that I could easier show you how to translate it into a functional style.

Comment: Thanks. I actually wrote the piece of code above as an example of a longer function. I didn't want to copy the function here because it's kinda long, but what gives, I'm gonna update the question.